# Use Vue.js value to check uncheck a checkbox

Tags: laravel-5.1, vue.js

I cant figure how to according to `@{{published}}` Vue.js value to check or uncheck a Checkbox, because `@{{published ==1? ... }}` doesnt work.

A solution which I would implement is to translate at the server side if published = 1 then convert to 'checked' and then remake the object array and then send it to the view, but Im looking for a straightforward answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model="published"`

http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html. not read the docs